# Check whether this matrix exist or not

Tags: linear-algebra

> Does there exist a non zero $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A^2 \neq 0$ and $A^3=0$, where $0$ is the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Vipra: Interrelate nilpotence and cayley Hamilton!

Answer (score 4):

If such a matrix exist,$f(x)=x^3$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$. Since minimal polynomial divides annihilating polynomials, $m(x)=x$ or $x^2$. Note that  $m(x)\neq x^3$, since the characteristic polynomial is of degree  $2$. If $m(x)=x$,we have $A =0$ and if $m(x)=x^2$,we have $A^2 =0$.

Hence such a matrix doesn't exist.